# Can I seperate instantiated vs. referenced variables in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Is there way to tell if a instance variable was instantiated inside of the class/object or is referenced from outside?

```
class A {
    b1 = new B();
    constructor(public b2:B) {}
}
```

I.e. I want to find the object properties / variables that are "owned" by the object (i.e. instantiated by itself, here b1) vs. the ones that are referenced (here b2).

Comment: `b2` is a parameter; it's local to the constructor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles to this in JS (I added the class def for B):

```
class B {
}
class A {
    constructor(b2) {
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b1 = new B();
    }
}
```

Which is what you have to work with unless you use a reflection library, or add annotations. So there is no API that I know of to simply output parameter names for the constructor.

If you still want to proceed and don't want to invest heavily, a cheap version of this may just be using some clever-enough regex on the output from `A.toString()` to detect parameter names and correlate them with member names on an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

Notice that the distinction is even more blurry than you might think: a constructor argument value might have been created solely for that instance, to be owned by it (`new A(new B())`), or an object that was created within the constructor of `A` might later become shared after it has been accessed from outside (`new C(a.b1)`). If you want to decide whether an object is "owned" by your `A` instances or not, you need to describe that contract in the documentation of your class (i.e. for its constructor, and the methods/accessors that might return a field).

Answer (score 1):

If we need smth owned it means it should be encapsulated and not available for public use. My proposition for you is to explicitly say that b1 is a private field. But in terms of which property was initialized in the constructor itself and which was at the field definition level is unknown.